# Add value to a geom_col with to variable on each column with geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made tree bar plot depending on health status (very good, good, bad) for each age groupe (variable 1) regarding their sexual status (variable 2). However, I cannot align the percentage value (which, for the example, is the sexual activity rate for variable 2) for each column. The percentage values are aligned vertically for each age group, I would like them to appear at the end of each column.

Here is my code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

ageC <- c("18-34","35+", "35+", "35+","35+","18-34","18-34","35+","18-34","35+")
health <- c("very good","very good", "bad", "bad", "good", "good", "bad", "very good", "good", "bad")
sexuality <- c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no")

df <- data.frame(ageC,health,sexuality)

df2 <- df %>%
  select(ageC, health, sexuality)

dff2 <- 
  df2 %>%
  group_by(ageC, health, sexuality) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), sexuality = str_squish(sexuality)) %>%
  ungroup() |>
  filter(sexuality == "yes") %>%
  mutate(health = fct_relevel(health, "very good", "good", "bad"))


ggplot(data = dff2) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = health, y = pct, x = ageC),
           width = 0.75, position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("very good" = "#cbd5e8", "good" = "#fdcdac", 
                               "bad" = "#b3e2cd" )) +
  facet_wrap(~sexuality) +
  labs(
    x = "Age class", y = "Percentage"
  ) +
  expand_limits(y = 1) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 18)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = pct, x = ageC, group = pct, label = percent(pct, accuracy = .1), family = "Times New Roman"),  
            vjust = 1.2, size = 2)
```

And the result [image]

Comment: Try `position = "dodge"` inside your `geom_text` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you have to tweak is `vjust` and `width` of `position_dodge()`

Here is a version with: `vjust = -0.5, size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = dff2) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = health, y = pct, x = ageC),
           width = 0.75, position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("very good" = "#cbd5e8", "good" = "#fdcdac", 
                               "bad" = "#b3e2cd" )) +
  facet_wrap(~sexuality) +
  labs(
    x = "Age class", y = "Percentage"
  ) +
  expand_limits(y = 1) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 18)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = pct, x = ageC, group = health, label = percent(pct, accuracy = .1), family = "Times New Roman"),  
            vjust = -0.5, size = 4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A slight rearrangement with placing the "aes()" definition into the main `ggplot()` call better defines the x coordinate for the labels.

```
ggplot(dff2, aes(fill = health, y = pct, x = ageC)) +
   geom_col(position =  'dodge') +
   scale_y_continuous(label = percent) +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("very good" = "#cbd5e8", "good" = "#fdcdac", "bad" = "#b3e2cd" )) +
   facet_wrap(~sexuality) +
   labs(x = "Age class", y = "Percentage") +
   expand_limits(y = 1) +
   theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman", size = 18)) +
   geom_text(aes(label=percent(pct, accuracy = .1)), position = position_dodge(width = .9), family = "Times New Roman",
             vjust = 1.2, size = 3)
```

[image]